# Stick html content to the right side

Tags: html, css

When you horizontally resize your browser window, you'll notice that the content on the right side undergoes rerendering, resulting in a noticeable flicker. Additionally, you'll observe the scrollbar being rerendered to a new position.
Is there a way to reverse this behavior so that the left side is rerendered while the right side is stable?

Comment: you can create a fixed-width layout for the left side of your content, so it remains stable, while the right side can be more flexible and responsive. This means setting a specific width for the left side (e.g., using CSS) and allowing the right side to adapt as needed.

Comment: no it will rerender right side and right side will ficker

Comment: You cannot influence how and when the browser needs to render the surrounding window. If you provide code maybe in your case it's an especially annoying case. But in general this is currently the way it is done. Some browsers allow you to style the scroll bar. Give all scroll bar elements the background color of your site (if you have a one-color background or a gradient that stops on the right) and change it back. Look at [window.resize event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event) if you want to try.

Comment: I'm not talking about about styling scrollbars. I'm talking about rerendering from left to rigth or from right to left. resize your browser window and observe that if you resizing right side you rerendering is visible but if you resize left side then it is not. the content is glued to the left side, even if you set the position absolute to right:0;

Comment: I mean..... `body{direction:rtl;}` will probably do what you want, but I don't think it's exactly what you're looking for.